# How to merge 2 jsons based on same value?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, tree

I am using a Angular Material Tree Control and would like to merge 2 jsons before setting to it. I want to merge them based on m_id, remove duplicates and also sort the objects within nodes based on sort_id value. I tried looking at solutions proposed in other threads but didn't find them working for deep structures. Any help/guidance will be appreciated.

For example:

**JSON1:**

```
var json1 = {
data: [{
        name: "Node 1",
        m_id: "node1",
        sort_id: 9,
        children: [{
                name: "Node 1_1",
                m_id: "node1_1",
                sort_id: 6,
                children: [{
                        name: "Node 1_1_1",
                        m_id: "node1_1_1",
                        sort_id: 9,
                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Node 1_1_2",
                        m_id: "node1_1_2",
                        sort_id: 2,
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Node 1_2",
                m_id: "node1_2",
                sort_id: 3,
                children: [{
                        name: "Node 1_2_1",
                        m_id: "node1_2_1",
                        sort_id: 1,
                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Node 1_2_2",
                        m_id: "node1_2_2",
                        sort_id: 5,
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Node 2",
        m_id: "node2",
        sort_id: 6,
        children: [{
                name: "Node 2_1",
                m_id: "node2_1",
                sort_id: 3,
                children: []
            },
            {
                name: "Node 2_2",
                m_id: "node2_2",
                sort_id: 2,
                children: []
            }
        ]
    }
]};
```

**JSON2:**

```
var json2 = {
    data: [{
            name: "Node 1",
            m_id: "node1",
            sort_id: 9,
            children: [{
                    name: "Node 1_1",
                    m_id: "node1_1",
                    sort_id: 6,
                    children: [{
                            name: "Node 1_1_1",
                            m_id: "node1_1_1",
                            sort_id: 9,
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Node 1_1_3",
                            m_id: "node1_1_3",
                            sort_id: 5,
                            children: []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Node 1_2",
                    m_id: "node1_2",
                    sort_id: 3,
                    children: [{
                            name: "Node 1_2_1",
                            m_id: "node1_2_1",
                            sort_id: 1,
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Node 1_2_2",
                            m_id: "node1_2_2",
                            sort_id: 5,
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Node 1_2_3",
                            m_id: "node1_2_3",
                            sort_id: 7,
                            children: []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Node 4",
            m_id: "node4",
            sort_id: 8,
            children: [{
                    name: "Node 4_1",
                    m_id: "node4_1",
                    sort_id: 4,
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    name: "Node 4_2",
                    m_id: "node4_2",
                    sort_id: 1,
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Give it a shot yourself, you're going to have to compare both arrays and check if there are elements with the same id. If not, push it in the result array. If yes, check the children of those elements recursively until you find a non dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Probably by using a library like lodash.

Simply parse the json, and then use https://lodash.com/docs/#merge.

Comment: merge is not working out. I am not getting the expected output. Also, tried     var merged = _.merge(
      _.keyBy(json1, "m_id"),
      _.keyBy(json2, "m_id")
    );
    var values = _.values(merged);
    console.log(values);

Comment: @johnk1 maybe you can make an example in codesandbox.io or similar so others can take that as starting point for getting an answer more quickly.